# R: Error compiling dbscan

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I can install dbscan on my laptop, no problem.
But it is not installing on a linux cluster I use for big data.
I have tried with R 3.3.3 and 3.4.0. I get the same error after invoking

```
install.packages("dbscan")
```

Error Message:

```
buildHDBSCAN.cpp(45): error: more than one operator "==" matches these operands:
        built-in operator "pointer == pointer"
        function "Rcpp::operator==(Rcpp::Na_Proxy, SEXP)"
        operand types are: Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19> == SEXP
if (!hcl.containsElementNamed("labels") || hcl["labels"] == R_NilValue){
                                                         ^

compilation aborted for buildHDBSCAN.cpp (code 2)
make: *** 


[/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2 /Compiler/intel2016.4/r/3.3.3/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:141: buildHDBSCAN.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dbscan’
 removing ‘/home/xxxxxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/dbscan’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpI1SJp8/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("dbscan") :
  installation of package ‘dbscan’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Well, works for everybody else [including CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_dbscan.html).  Is your C++ compiler by chance from the stone age?  Ancient RH or CentOS maybe?

Comment: Bingo on the latter! CentOS. I guessed as much and have emailed the support team. Any idea what they need to do to make their compiler compatible? (I'm not a c programmer)

Comment: Use one from this decade, rather than the previous one.